# speech recognition for android apps

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech

Is there any suggestions for what tools to be use to develop an offline foreign language speech recognition?
I'm currently working hard on study how to create an acoustic model to train the system to understand Malay language by using eclipse in java language.
is it OK to use PocketSphinx?

Answer (score 2):

Sphinx / PocketSphinx is an excellent pick. To train acoustic models though, you would need a large database of recorded and consistently tagged speech data [tagged with the words which were spoken], and a phonetic dictionary which contains the phonetic transcriptions for those words. On top of that you will also need to train a language model, and for that you'd need a large or very large text corpus in your target language.

This is more like a research project in terms of the volume of things to do.. good luck!

I'm not sure what you mean by "... by using eclipse in java language."

Comment: i plan to use eclipse to develop this apps. i really need a lot guide to do this project. thanks for the reply

Comment: eclipse? the JAVA-based IDE?? that has nothing to do with speech recognition.